# How to Get Edit text only accept texting if user put a specific number in first

Tags: android, android-edittext

how do you get it so that edit text only accepts text if the user had puttet a `K` in to start with
like

1. KV1096
2. K0024

Answer (score 1):

In android, there is a listener for text change:

```
EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);

//now you can add the listener here:
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             // here get the value entered by user and get the character
             //at index 0; 
             String value = "what the user has entered".charAt(0)
             //now use an if statement here to see if it is your required value (K); if not, set EditText to disabled - not active;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps you get started!

Comment: doesn't String value = "what the user has entered".charAt(0) have to be a char instead of string? as it says is incompatible types

Comment: Sure you can make it a char